# why the job has been submitted using qsub is unknown?

Tags: bash, pbs, qsub

In regard to create a PBS script file to run long-term jobs on a server with 256 GB of RAM and two CPUs, each with 12 cores and 24 threads, yielding 48 computing unit. I tried to do it, but I think there is something wrong.
I created a PBS script named run_trinity and submitted it to server using qsub command (qsub run_trinity.sh) within the same directory that contain my desired program (trinity) and data, and it returned something like 47.chpc. But when I tried to check the status of job using qstat command, it says: unknown job id 47.chpc. I'm a biology student and really new in this field, could you please help me to figure out what happened? here is my PBS script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N run_trinity
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=6
#PBS -l walltime=100:00:00
#PBS -l mem=200gb
#PBS -j oe
#Set stack size to unlimited
ulimit -s unlimited

cd /home/mary/software/trinityrnaseq_r20140717

perl /home/mary/software/trinityrnaseq_r20140717/Trinity.pl --seqType fq --JM 200G --normalize_reads --left reads8_1.fq.gz --right reads8_2.fq.gz --SS_lib_type FR --CPU 6 --full_cleanup --output /home/mary/software/trinityrnaseq_r20140717
```

Looking forward to hearing your perfect solutions.

Comment: Please add your script to your question. It is near impossible to debug what we can't see.

Comment: OK friend, I added the code

Comment: Perhaps your job has already exited? Are there any output files? Normally they will have a name like run_trinity.e47 and be in the directory that you have `cd`d to.

Comment: Thanks friend. Yes, there is file named run_trinity.o47, but when I tried to open it using cat, I faced with "PBS: exec of shell '' failed". It sound that the job was immediately failed. Could you please help me what is the problem and how to solve it? Thanks so much